# What Differences Are There Between Form Submissions and cURL Requests?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I'm trying to submit data to SalesForce.com, but I'd like to do it through AJAX. Since there are restrictions to deter XSS, I'm having jQuery use AJAX to submit to a PHP page on my server and then having that page simply forward the formdata it's passed along to the proper URL.

If I submit the form with JS turned off, everything goes through fine. If I turn it on, Salesforce confirms receipt of the data (in debug mode), but it's not showing up in my queue, or anywhere really, in SF. SF spits back all of the fields it was passed, and it's spitting back every field that I have in my form, properly filled out.

Are there any differences between submitting something through this method (jQuery's `$.ajax()` to PHP cURL) and through the native HTML Submit button? Something that could be causing SF to register the data, but register it differently? I've tried adding `CURLOPT_HEADER`/`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` information

Comment: I know nothing about SF, but would it be expecting a `Cookie` header along with the POST date, which cURL may not be sending?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - do forms use cookies? I'm not passing any cookies around on this page without AJAX, what would it be looking for there?

Comment: The USER_AGENT header is one thing that is going to be notably different. Also, as @TRiG says, the browser would be carrying some cookies in every request it makes - session info for example. It could be that salesforce is sensitive to that. You can find info here on SO on how to deal with curl and cookies: Search "curl cookies" or "cookiejar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the only thing that's different that you can't fake is the IP address of the request.  Depending on how tough the protection is that salesforce is using, you may not be able to spoof from a separate IP address (it would detect and deny the request).

Everything else should be 100% fakeable (headers, etc).  What I would suggest is that you get firebug or TamperData and look at the raw headers being sent to salesforce from your browser normally.  Then replicate that exact request from PHP.  If you need other information, you could detect it in JS and pass it to PHP (Cookie information, browser info, etc)...

Comment: There's no IP specification, of that I'm sure. How can I get Firebug to tell me about form posts? I've been trying, but all I can capture is AJAX requests etc.

Comment: Well, you should be able to capture anything from Firebug.  But I personally like [`Tamper Data`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) since it lets you test out modifications directly.  Just turn it on, and it'll show you the requests, or let you pause them and edit them prior to submission if you want...  And are you sure that there's no IP check in the session code?  Since you're passing the session cookie, it might do a sanity check to see if the cookie is at least coming from the proper IP address...

Comment: At this point I'm not _intentionally_ passing a session cookie. Also, I'm using FF4b9, so Tamper Data doesn't seem to be an option and Firebug doesn't seem to be capturing POSTs. What a pain!

Comment: While I can't seem to solve my problem, it does seem to be the correct answer to my question, "What differences are there…?" so I'm marking it as correct. I'm guessing it's something on SFDC's end and I'll have to try to figure it out with them.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax() transmits cookies from the client browser; and it also adds a "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" request header.

Comment: Would that header be automatically forwarded with cURL? Because otherwise I don't think that's getting passed on. Either way though that's good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding the (external) IP address of the machine that is running the php code to the list of trusted networks in salesforce. Login to salesforce, and go to setup -> security controls -> network access, and add the IP there.

I ran into a similar problem and had to add the ip address of the server that was running the java app that connected to sf and this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything for me, but thanks. I think that since I'm just submitting a form (and that form request could be coming from any user's browser), they're not too strict on the IP thing there.