# axios Cross-Origin Request Blocked Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-domain, axios

I try to make a simple GET call with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Lets say I have the following code:

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.get('https://www.wikipedia.org/')
```

The browser (Firefox) logs the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.wikipedia.org/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

In the `Developer Toolbar - Network` there is the right response.

When I copy the request as cURL and past it in the console it works.

Is this a problem with `axios`, `firefox` or `wikipedia.org`?

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS error while making axios.get call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164116/cors-error-while-making-axios-get-call)

Comment: But why is this a server problem? cURL works, and also direct call to the url works...

Comment: `axios` is an AJAX request, while CURL is a `server` request. In simpler words, CURL is a separate browser, while axios is your server. Since you don't own the wikipedia server, you cannot really access Wikipedia's server items from your server asynchronously using XMLHttpRequest

Comment: It’s unclear from you question what actual data you’re really trying to get from Wikipedia. But if what you’re really do is trying to use the Wikipedia *API*, then see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733007/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing-from-wikipedia-api-response/47733422#47733422. The gist of it is, you need to add `origin=*` to the query string.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775592/ajax-versus-curl#comment-5297587) comment, AJAX is limited by the same origin policy while cURL is not.

Thats what was not clear from [CORS error while making axios.get call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164116/cors-error-while-making-axios-get-call). It was just a solution for the problem with no explanation.

Thanks for the comments. If you are interested in access wikipedia see [zuifs comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330196/axios-cross-origin-request-blocked-firefox#comment-83647027).